# How to improve a Nuxt.js powered site for Google PageSpeed insights

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I have a website under development built with Nuxt.js.

It works really great but since the first loading takes a couple of seconds, with a blank page, Google PageSpeed insights are really poor for mobile.

Test website here: http://eventscace-354711072.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/

They claim the initial painful content is taking 10 seconds or more.

I’m pretty sure it is related somehow to the loading of VueX. So
I was wondering if there is a way to speed up or put something in that white page at least while it loads.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have checked your website with page audits. you scored 1% of 100% thats extremly bad. if you use google chrome press F12 then go to "audits" and check the page you will get all results and how to improve speed

Comment: I know but I don’t know hot to make nuxt deliver content instantly while it loads the rest. I am pretty sure that would leverage performance. That is my original question. Thanks

Comment: you have lot of things in your `assets` folder. That wont get cached so you load it over and over again. Put more content in your `static` folder. The first load will be longer but the second load will load everything out of the cache

Comment: your images are also too big. for example the american express logo. its 300x300 but in an 50x50 div

Comment: The leading technologies such as lazy load component, purgecss, and split will be very useful.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran your site through https://webpagetest.org and it shows nicely where it spends the time. I just noticed:

- loading jquery multiple times (why jquery with vue in the first place?)
- big and many css (purge-css?)
- you are loading a lot of fonts
- third party JS after loading GTM
- run nuxt build with analyze set to true and see where the big JS is in your app
- image size?

Anyway, many small steps I think.